# Informix group by hour

Tags: datetime, informix, hour

How one does use the group by clause with hour in Informix?

The group by section here gives an error:

```
  SELECT
     cqdr.targetid, 
     cqdr.profileid, 
     ccdr.startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR AS CallHour,
     Count(cqdr.sessionid), 
     (Sum(cqdr.queuetime) / Count(cqdr.sessionid)), 
     Max(cqdr.queuetime)
   FROM Contactqueuedetail cqdr, Contactcalldetail ccdr, Selected_csqs sc
   WHERE cqdr.sessionid = ccdr.sessionid AND
         cqdr.sessionseqnum = ccdr.sessionseqnum AND
         cqdr.profileid = ccdr.profileid AND
         cqdr.nodeid = ccdr.nodeid AND
         ccdr.startdatetime BETWEEN DATE('12/6/27') AND DATE('12/6/28') AND 
         --cqdr.targettype = l_typecsq AND
         cqdr.targetid = sc.csqrecordid AND
         cqdr.profileid = sc.profileid
   GROUP BY ccdr.startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR, cqdr.targetid, cqdr.profileid;
```

Answer (score 2):

To group by derived columns, use the GROUP BY ordinal position syntax:

```
SELECT cqdr.targetid, 
     cqdr.profileid, 
     ccdr.startdatetime::DATETIME HOUR TO HOUR AS CallHour,
     Count(cqdr.sessionid), 
     (Sum(cqdr.queuetime) / Count(cqdr.sessionid)), 
     Max(cqdr.queuetime)
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: It does appear that although you can ORDER BY expressions and even display labels (column aliases in the select-list), you cannot do the same with GROUP BY.